# In MongoDB, how do we apply filter criteria on a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the below collection called "Survey" having 1000 documents out of which i am taking 2 as an example here.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000007"),
     "name": "Asger systems",
    "content": [
      {
        "content_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "placebo": true,
        "type": "tt"
      },
      {
        "content_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "placebo": false,
        "type": "pp"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000008"),
    "name": "DCCC here it goes",
    "content": [
      {
        "content_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "placebo": false,
        "type": "cc"
      },
      {
        "content_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "placebo": true,
        "type": "Multiple"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i actually want to **"Find the percentage of surveys (which have "DCCC" in the name) that have at least one content which has content type = Multiple"**

I am able to build the query for counting the total number of documents and then filtering for name using **db.Survey.find( { name: { $regex: /DCCC/ } } ).countDocuments()** but now i am confused as in how will i filter a subdocument which is a value inside type field. Also, i am not sure how will i find the percentage.Please help and tell me if i am in the right direction or not.

Answer (score 0):

To filter the document with at least one element with `{ type: "Multiple" }` in `content` array, you can use dot notation as below:

```
db.Survey.find({
  name: {
    $regex: /DCCC/
  },
  "content.type": "Multiple"
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nEQaXef4Sov)

While performing the percentage of surveys, the formula:

```
percentage = (number of filtered document(s) / total number of documents) * 100
```

Hence, it would be something like:

```js
let filteredCount = db.Survey.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "DCCC"
  },
  "content.type": "Multiple"
}).countDocuments();

let totalCount = db.Survey.find({}).countDocuments();

let percentage = (filteredCount / totalCount) * 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Just curious to know if i can run your all lines starting with let inside MongoDB Compass CLI?

Comment: No, the whole code is JavaScript. I don't think you can execute JavaScript code in MongoDB Compass CLI.